# Persistent loading of a PEM key/certificate pair for HTTPS connections in Python 2.x (6, 7)

Tags: python, ssl, get, ssl-certificate, pem

I'm trying to fetch (`GET`) some resources from a SSL-secured Web service. For authenticating into the service, I have a PEM pair of key-certificate files. I'm using a slightly expanded version (see the bottom) of [this client](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577548-https-httplib-client-connection-with-certificate-v/) to connect to the service.

My issue is: After processing the contents of a request, I will issue further requests over the same socket/connection. The code structure goes like this:

```
conn = HTTPSClientAuthConnection("a host name", 443,
                                 key_file=a_key_file,
                                 cert_file=a_cert_file,
                                 ca_file=None)

full_page, response = conn.do_request(the_main_url)
further_requests = process_page(full_page)

for ref in further_requests:
    new_data, response = conn.do_request(ref)
    print process_data(new_data)
```

The annoyance is that for every invocation of `do_request`, the passphrase for the cert/key pair is requested. **How can I** make that persistent? I'm attempting to implement this client with only Python's stdlib, as the machines I'll be running it are not easily modified. But if that's not possible, a good library suggestion is welcome as well...

```
$ python get-ssl-data.py 
Enter PEM pass phrase: <I enter the passphrase>
<the first request has no output to stdout>

Enter PEM pass phrase: <I enter the passphrase>
<output of this step>

Enter PEM pass phrase: <I enter the passphrase>
<output of this step>

Enter PEM pass phrase: <I enter the passphrase>
<output of this step>
...
```

SSL client code:

```
import socket
import ssl
import httplib

class HTTPSClientAuthConnection(httplib.HTTPSConnection):
    """ Class to make a HTTPS connection, with support for full client-based SSL Authentication"""

    def __init__(self, host, port, key_file, cert_file, ca_file, timeout=None):
        httplib.HTTPSConnection.__init__(self, host, key_file=key_file, cert_file=cert_file)
        self.key_file = key_file
        self.cert_file = cert_file
        self.ca_file = ca_file
        self.timeout = timeout

    def connect(self):
        """ Connect to a host on a given (SSL) port.
            If ca_file is pointing somewhere, use it to check Server Certificate.

            Redefined/copied and extended from httplib.py:1105 (Python 2.6.x).
            This is needed to pass cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED as parameter to ssl.wrap_socket(),
            which forces SSL to check server certificate against our client certificate.
        """
        sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
        if self._tunnel_host:
            self.sock = sock
            self._tunnel()
        # If there's no CA File, don't force Server Certificate Check
        if self.ca_file:
            self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, ca_certs=self.ca_file, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)
        else:
            self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)

    def do_request (self, url, method='GET', keep_alive=True):

        headers = {}

        if keep_alive:
            headers["Connection"] = "keep-alive"

        self.request(method, url, headers=headers)
        response = self.getresponse()
        data = response.read()

        return data, response
```